# Learning JavaScript and ajax, having problems with localhost

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, client-side

I'm learning javascript with a book called JavaScript in steps, i'm stuck in a chapter called producing web applications, it explains AJAX techniques, there is a part where you write code in JS XML and some HTML with CSS. it says: "open the html file via http", i cant figure out how to do that.

do i need MAMP, XAMPP? or how do i create my localhost server ?

Heres my HTMl code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Request XML</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="request-xml.js"> </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="panel">
<button id="btn">Request XML</button>
</div> 
</body>

</html>
```

my JS code

```
var panel , request ;

function showXML()
{
  if ( (request.readyState === 4 ) && ( request.status === 200 ) )
  { 
    var i , names =  request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName( "name" ) ;
    for ( i = 0 ; i < names.length ; i++ )
    {
      panel.innerHTML += "<br>" + names[ i ].firstChild.data ;
    }
  }
}

function doRequest()
{
  request = new XMLHttpRequest() ;
  request.open( "GET" , "data.xml" , true ) ;
  request.send( null ) ;
  request.onreadystatechange = showXML ;
}

function init()
{
  panel = document.getElementById( "panel" ) ;
  document.getElementById( "btn" ).onclick = doRequest ;
}
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded" , init , false ) ;
```

and xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<members>
    <number>001</number> <name>Anne</name>
    <number>002</number> <name>Beverly</name>
    <number>003</number> <name>Carmen</name>
</members>
```

Comment: wat os r u using Mac/Windows ...

Comment: U can use Mamp for Mac will do good..http://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/

Comment: Ugh - those are terrible instructions! "Open the file" usually means go to your browser and select File|Open from the menu.  No webserver needed.  However if it says "http" then you would need to run a web server (MAMP is fine, as is lighttp, or other super-lightweight web servers).  But, wow.  The authors could have worded that better.

Comment: ok, and where do i put my files?, in htdocs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Mac osx you have python.

open your terminal, browse to the project root directory (the folder with the index.html file) and type:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888
```

that will create a local HTTP server on port 8888.

after you've done that, just browse to 127.0.0.1:8888

hope that helps.